# Running date and time by adding minutes per row in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following data :

| RUN | WORKORDER | LOCATION | TRAVELTIME | NUMEQUIP | TOT_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NO99 | 1 | Start |  |  |  |
| NO99 | 2 | Customer 1 | 112 | 1 | 8 |
| NO99 | 3 | Customer 2 | 18 | 11 | 88 |
| NO99 | 4 | Customer 3 | 22 | 93 | 744 |
| NO99 | 5 | Customer 4 | 34 | 3 | 24 |

i will pass by parameter some values, and 2 of those parameters will be starting date and starting time ...

I need to get the following output :

| RUN | WORKORDER | LOCATION | TRAVELTIME | NUMEQUIP | TOT_TIME | DATE | TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NO99 | 1 | Start |  |  |  | 10/05/22 | 9:00 |
| NO99 | 2 | Customer 1 | 112 | 1 | 8 | 10/05/22 | 10:52 |
| NO99 | 3 | Customer 2 | 18 | 11 | 88 | 10/05/22 | 11:18 |
| NO99 | 4 | Customer 3 | 22 | 93 | 744 | 10/05/22 | 14:08 |
| NO99 | 5 | Customer 4 | 34 | 3 | 24 | 12/05/22 | 10:06 |

This result is achieved by calculating the estimated time to make the trip between customers (TRAVELTIME), and after arriving is also added the time spent on maintenance (TOT_TIME that is Number of Equipments (NUMEQUIP) vs 8 minutes per equipment)... By this, and since customer 3 will have 744 minutes (12 h and 58 minutes) in maintenance... and those minutes will spawn through 3 days, the result should be as shown...

With the following query i can have almost the desired effect... but cannot take into account only work hours ... and all time is continuous...

```
SELECT TBL1.RUN,TBL1.WORKORDER,TBL1.LOCATION, 
DATEADD(MI,TEMPTIME,'09:00') AS WORKORDERDATETIME
 FROM (SELECT RUN, WORKORDER, LOCATION, 
SUM(TRAVELTIME+TOT_TIME) OVER (ORDER BY WORKORDER) 
as TEMPTIME FROM MYTABLE WHERE RUN='NO99' )AS TBL1
```

I need to have the Date and Time columns to be updated using both TRAVELTIME and TOT_TIME, but if the Time goes above 13:00, an hour should be added to the TIME, and if the time goes above 18:00, 15 hours should be added to the time and a day to the date...

All movements are done using the Workorder to define the ORDER...

I can use a sum to create a tempruntime using "Over (Order by table.Workorder)"... But if possible i would prefer to use a stored procedure and create some type of variable that would be updated per Workorder line...

Comment: “With the following query…” but you seemed to have forgotten to add the query to your question (as editable text, not images)

Comment: Sorry, forgot query ...